# How to merge multiple xts dataframe to a single data frame

Tags: r

I have two datasets; dataset1 and dataset2.

```
dataset1
               DayofWeek   EMA GOOG.Close
    2015-10-15     Thurs  7.85         UP
    2015-10-16       Fri  8.00       DOWN
    2015-10-19       Mon  8.18         UP
    2015-10-20      Tues  5.39       DOWN
    2015-10-21       Wed  2.38       DOWN
    2015-10-22     Thurs  1.98         UP
    2015-10-23       Fri  9.25       DOWN
    2015-10-26       Mon 14.29         UP
    2015-10-27      Tues 15.52         UP
    2015-10-28       Wed 15.93         UP
    2015-10-29     Thurs 15.79         UP
    2015-10-30       Fri 13.83       DOWN
```

and

```
dataset2
           DayofWeek   EMA AAPL.Close
2015-10-15     Thurs  0.26         UP
2015-10-16       Fri  0.18       DOWN
2015-10-19       Mon  0.23         UP
2015-10-20      Tues  0.55         UP
2015-10-21       Wed  0.69       DOWN
2015-10-22     Thurs  0.99         UP
2015-10-23       Fri  1.64         UP
2015-10-26       Mon  1.31       DOWN
2015-10-27      Tues  0.95       DOWN
2015-10-28       Wed  1.41         UP
2015-10-29     Thurs  1.76         UP
2015-10-30       Fri  1.69       DOWN
```

I want to merge both dataset1 and dataset2 to get a new dataset3 like this

```
dataset3
           DayofWeek   EMA      Close
2015-10-15     Thurs  7.85         UP
2015-10-16       Fri  8.00       DOWN
2015-10-19       Mon  8.18         UP
2015-10-20      Tues  5.39       DOWN
2015-10-21       Wed  2.38       DOWN
2015-10-22     Thurs  1.98         UP
2015-10-23       Fri  9.25       DOWN
2015-10-26       Mon 14.29         UP
2015-10-27      Tues 15.52         UP
2015-10-28       Wed 15.93         UP
2015-10-29     Thurs 15.79         UP
2015-10-30       Fri 13.83       DOWN
2015-10-15     Thurs  0.26         UP
2015-10-16       Fri  0.18       DOWN
2015-10-19       Mon  0.23         UP
2015-10-20      Tues  0.55         UP
2015-10-21       Wed  0.69       DOWN
2015-10-22     Thurs  0.99         UP
2015-10-23       Fri  1.64         UP
2015-10-26       Mon  1.31       DOWN
2015-10-27      Tues  0.95       DOWN
2015-10-28       Wed  1.41         UP
2015-10-29     Thurs  1.76         UP
2015-10-30       Fri  1.69       DOWN
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the data.  Have you tried `?merge`?  You can check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075555/merging-xts-objects)

Comment: Tried like this `merged.data <- merge(DataSet[[1]], DataSet[[2]])` dataset are saved in lists. `merged.data` shows this `[1] DayofWeek  EMA        GOOG.Close AAPL.Close
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about syncing the column names then simply rbinding them together?

```
names(dataset1)<-names(dataset2)
dataset3 <- rbind(dataset1,dataset2)
```

You can always change the last column name to `Close` afterwards.